# constructing java code that generates numbers 1-100 and displays only composite integers

Tags: java

Here is my attempt(and failure) at writing a java application that displays integers that are only composite in the range of integers from 1 to 100

> //a java application that prints out composite numbers that range from 1 to 100

```
>//public class printcomposites{

>//main exceutes java application
>public static void main(String[] args){
>//loop to iterate all candidate values from 1 through 100
>for( int i = 1 ; i <=99 ; i++ )
>{


> // a nested loop to define the divisors of the candidate values
>// what should ?? be for an efficient program?
>for ( int j = 1 ; j <= i ; j++ )``
>{



> // a statement to identify composite numbers from the candidate value
>if ( i%j==0 )
>{
>// collect or display the identified composite numbers

>j=j+i;
>System.out.printf("%d\t",j);

>}//end if

> }//end
```

My code displays all integers from 1-100 instead of integers that are only composite integers. Where did I go wrong

Comment: define composite please?

Comment: @almasshaikh composite means numbers which are not prime

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

- You have j starting with 1 and every number is divisible by 1.
- You have condition j <= i, every number is divisible by itself.
- Once you find that number is divisible by other then you should stop processing further and break from inner loop.
- You already know 2 is prime so exclude it and start your i loop from 3.

You should have something like:

```
 for (int i = 3; i <= 99; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= i/2; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
                break;
            }// end if
        }
 }
```

Comment: In the second loop the condition can be changed to `j<=i/2` which can reduce some iterations.

Comment: `j < i/2` wont print `4` which is composite so it has to be `j<=i/2`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong here.

1. You were missing a few close brackets, but that could've been a copy error
2. You were incrementing j... the for loop does that for you
3. You were printing j: i is the number in question, j is just a method to ascertain it
4. You were checking for divisions of 1 and the number itself, which will always be true
5. It was pretty inefficient... once you have determined composite, close the loop

Here is what it should look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    for( int i = 2 ; i <=99 ; i++ ) //iterate 1 - 99; 2 is prime
    {
        for ( int j = 2 ; j < i ; j++ ) //iterate 2 - potential composite EXCLUSIVELY; every number can be divided by one and itself
        {
            if (i%j==0 ) //test to see if the given number less than i is a factor of i
            {
                System.out.println(i); //i is a composite, because it has a factor, j. Print it.
                break; //we already know it's a composite, no need to keep testing
            }

        }
    }
}
```